# Getting geography locations in radius

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgis

I have table looking like:

```
CREATE TABLE public.places
    (
        id bigint DEFAULT nextval('places_id_seq'::regclass) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
        lon numeric(18,13) DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
        lat numeric(18,13) DEFAULT NULL::numeric,
        location geography(Point,4326)
    );
    CREATE INDEX places_ll ON public.places (lon, lat);
    CREATE INDEX places_location_ix ON public.places (location);
    INSERT INTO public.places (id, lon, lat, location) VALUES (1, 14.4783371228873, 46.0299536240291, '0101000020E610000003CD3585D50347400287769AE8F42C40');
```

Now I wan't to find nearby location with query:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.47859, 46.02998166)), location) as dist, lon, lat, location FROM places
WHERE ST_DWithin(Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.47859, 46.02998166)), Geography(location), 50) ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1;
```

I get zero results. Then I try query:

```
SELECT ST_Distance(Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.47859, 46.02998166)), ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)) as dist, lon, lat, location FROM places
WHERE ST_DWithin(Geography(ST_MakePoint(14.47859, 46.02998166)), Geography(ST_MakePoint(lon,lat)), 50) ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1;
```

And I get a result:

```
14.4783371228873    46.0299536240291    0101000020E610000003CD3585D50347400287769AE8F42C40
```

The problem is that the second query returns result but is much much slower, as opposed to first one, which does not return result but is very fast (indexed search). Of course I'd like the mixture of both. Not surprisingly I want results and fast as it can be.

Comment: Unrelated: why do you keep x,y and the geography in the same table?

Comment: Unrelated - if you create index on gegography/geometry create GIST index not btree index CREATE INDEX ON public.places  using GIST(location);
Btree don't work with ST_Dwithin and other functions

Comment: Also you can get your lat and long from geom as st_x(location) and st_y(location) .don't use lon lat as separate columns it is redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your coordinate pairs are probably inverted. Keep in mind that [`ST_MakePoint`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_MakePoint.html) expects *x,y*, not *y,x*. Either you have your point somewhere in Yemen - `POINT(46.0299536240291 14.4783371228873)`:

[image]

Or in Slovenia - `POINT(14.4783371228873 46.0299536240291)`:

[image]

Either the geography column or your coordinate pair at `ST_MakePoint` are inverted.

Also, the geography function - used in your query as `Geography(location)` - in a *geography* type column is redundant. It seems you're also attempting to store *x,y* in separated columns and then you're inserting the same values in a geography column. If you can, get rid of the *x,y* columns, since they're also redundant... the *geography* is enough.

In case x,y are `46.02998166,14.47859` Try this:

```
SELECT 
  ST_Distance(Geography(ST_MakePoint(46.02998166,14.47859)), location) AS dist, 
  lon, lat, ST_AsText(location) 
FROM places
WHERE 
  ST_DWithin(Geography(ST_MakePoint(46.02998166,14.47859)), 
  location, 50) ORDER BY dist LIMIT 1;

    dist     |       lon        |       lat        |                st_astext                 
-------------+------------------+------------------+------------------------------------------
 28.14204157 | 14.4783371228873 | 46.0299536240291 | POINT(46.0299536240291 14.4783371228873)
```

Comment: Yes, I understand that lat/lon fields are redundant so they will be removed. Point is in Slovenia. And it seams that query from @Jim-Jones solves all my problems. It is indexed search and it returns results. So thank you (and all other).

Answer (score 0):

The `location` and the point you create have lat-long inverted.  It is understandable that the two queries takes a different amount of time (use of index to filter out all rows instead of computing / sorting the exact distance)

```
select st_astext('0101000020E610000003CD3585D50347400287769AE8F42C40');
                st_astext
------------------------------------------
 POINT(46.0299536240291 14.4783371228873)
```